# Polybius Square Javascript Map Function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures, methods

I'm working on a problem solving a polybius square functionality. I am having trouble figuring out how to create a polybius square function. with the following instructions:

The polybius()
function in the src/polybius.js
file has two parameters:

input refers to the inputted text to be encoded or decoded.
encode refers to whether you should encode or decode the message. By default it is set to true
.
When building the function, keep the following constraints and rules in mind:

You are welcome to assume that no additional symbols will be included as part of the input. Only spaces and letters will be included.
When encoding, your output should still be a string.
When decoding, the number of characters in the string excluding spaces should be even. Otherwise, return false
.
Spaces should be maintained throughout.
Capital letters can be ignored.
The letters "I" and "J" share a space. When encoding, both letters can be converted to 42
, but when decoding, both letters should somehow be shown.

& basically, I got to here with my code:

```
    const cipher = (input, encode = true) => {
  const direction = encode ? encoder : decoder;

  return input
    .match(/[0-9]{2}|[a-z]|\s/g)
    .map(character => direction[character] || character)
    .join('');
};
```

but i'm lost on how I would do this for the i/j exception when I am decoding a string. Any thoughts?

```
    const encoder = { 'a': '11', 'b': '12', 'c': '13', 'd': '14', 'e': '15', 'f': '21', 'g': '22', 'h': '23', 'i/j': '24', 'k': '25', 'l': '31', 'm': '32', 'n': '33', 'o': '34', 'p': '35', 'q': '41', 'r': '42', 's': '43', 't': '44', 'u': '45', 'v': '51', 'w': '52', 'x': '53', 'y': '54', 'z': '55' };
const decoder = { '11': 'a', '12': 'b', '13': 'c', '14': 'd', '15': 'e', '21': 'f', '22': 'g', '23': 'h', '24': 'i/j', '25': 'k', '31': 'l', '32': 'm', '33': 'n', '34': 'o', '35': 'p', '41': 'q', '42': 'r', '43': 's', '44': 't', '45': 'u', '51': 'v', '52': 'w', '53': 'x', '54': 'y', '55': 'z' };
```

**TL:DR -> Need to figure out how to use the .map function for i/j exception for decoding a polybius string**

Comment: Would it not be that `decoder[42] = "i/j"`, `encoder['i'] = 42` and `encoder['j'] = 42`?

Comment: I'm kinda confused on how to implement that though because .map iteration doesn't have any breaks to check that condition right?

Comment: `.map` doesn't care that two keys in your `encoder` have the same value, nor that `decoder` has two values for a key.

Comment: so I should be making another if statement? how would I check that using the code I wrote?

Comment: The code you have is fine, as long as `encoder` and `decoder` are defined correctly. Can you share `encoder` and `decoder`?

Comment: yup I added the encoder and decoder and the encoding works just the decoder for i/j is off because it doesn't understand the difference of values between i and j

Comment: Yeah, that's your problem. Replace `const encoder = { ... 'i/j': '24', ... };` with `const encoder = { ... 'i': '24', 'j': '24', ... };` and you should be fine.

Comment: right right, but the only issue is that I can't replace the i/j values as the requirement is to figure out a way to use the say key for those values but also when decoding to know when the actual letter character is

Answer (score 0):

Try with these:

```
var txt=txt.toLowerCase().replace('j','i') 
var r='' 
for(var a=0;a0){ 
    if(t.substr(0,1)==' '){ 
        r+=' ' 
        c=1 
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).